# Extract values from data frame in R

Tags: r

Using R, I would like to find out which Samples (S1, S2, S3, S4, S5) fulfill the following criteria:contain minimally one value (x, y or z) bigger than 4. Thanks, Alex.

```
 Sample    x    y    z <br>
     S1 -0.3  5.3  2.5 <br>
     S2  0.4  0.2 -1.2 <br>
     S3  1.2 -0.6  3.2 <br>
     S4  4.3  0.7  5.7 <br>
     S5  2.4  4.3  2.3 <br>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a call to `apply` - for example:

```
> apply(dataFrameOfSamples,1,function(x)any(x > 4))
   S1    S2    S3    S4    S5
 TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: ... assuming that Sample is the name of the data frame or matrix rather than just a column of said data frame.

Answer (score 0):

How does this sound? Copy your data into your clipboard and execute the following commands:

```
dta <- read.table("clipboard", header = T)
apply(dta[2:4], 1, function(x) ifelse(max(x) >= 4, 1, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

With many rows this could be more efficient:

```
do.call(pmax, X[c("x","y","z")]) > 4
```

On your data

```
ex <- data.frame(
  Sample = c("S1", "S2", "S3", "S4", "S5"),
  x = c(-0.3, 0.4, 1.2, 4.3, 2.4),
  y = c( 5.3, 0.2,-0.6, 0.7, 4.3),
  z = c( 2.5,-1.2, 3.2, 5.7, 2.3)
)

do.call(pmax, ex[c("x","y","z")]) > 4
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

**Benchmark summary**: the `pmax` approach could not only be more efficient as @MArek suggest, it is a lot more efficient than the other two. It loses some of it's advantage when a data frame has more columns but it is still the fastest approach.

**Benchmark**. Being an empiricist I took the liberty of comparing the three approaches. The 3 approaches were compared using `microbenchmark`. These are varied characteristics:

- The three approaches here called “pmax” (by @Marek), “apply.any” (by @nullglob), “apply.ifelse” (by @roman-luštrik)
- Size of data frame

  - Number of rows: 10, 500, 2500
  - Number of columns: 4, 500, 2500

The performance of the `pmax` approach is remarkable. It is a lot faster. For the smallest data frame it has an advantage by a factor of > 3. For 2500 rows and 4 columns `pmax` is over 97 times faster than “apply.ifelse” and 57 times faster than "apply.any".

[image: Required duration to run the benchmark]

The following images shows the performance of the three approaches in relation to `pmax`. Hence, the performance of `pmax` in each combination of rows and columns is always 1 (i.e. 100%) and the other two approaches are shown in relation to that. It shows that the performance of `pmax` is superior especially for the data frames with fewer columns.

Since `pmax` seems to lose it's advantage with an increasing number of column, it could be that the other approaches become faster with a large number of columns.

[image: Benchmark standardised to the pmax approach]

**Code used in this post:**

```r
library(microbenchmark)

TotalResult <- list()
for (Width in c(4, 500, 1000)) {
  for (Size in c(10, 500, 2500)) {
    ex <- data.frame(
      Sample = paste0("S", 1:Size),
      x = runif(Size, 0, 6),
      y = runif(Size, 0, 6),
      z = runif(Size, 0, 6)
    )
    if (Width > 4)
      for (i in 5:Width)
        ex[[i]] <- runif(Size, 0, 6)

    result <- microbenchmark(
      pmax = { do.call(pmax, ex[2:Width]) > 4 },
      apply.ifelse = { apply(ex[2:Width], 1, function(x) ifelse(max(x) > 4, TRUE, FALSE)) },
      apply.any = apply(ex[2:Width], 1, function(x) any(x > 4)),
      check = "identical"
    )
    cat("Benchmark: Size =", Size, "// Width =", Width, "\n")
    print(result)
    #boxplot(result)
    TotalResult <- c(TotalResult, list(list(Size=Size, Width=Width, Benchmark=result)))
  }
}


Comparison <- data.frame(Approach = character(),
                         Rows   = numeric(),
                         Columns  = numeric(),
                         Duration = double())
for(test in TotalResult) {
  x <- by(test$Benchmark$time, test$Benchmark$expr, median)
  Comparison <- rbind(Comparison,
                      data.frame(
                        Approach = unlist(attr(x, "dimnames")),
                        Rows = test$Size, Columns = test$Width, 
                        Duration = unclass(x)
                      ))
}
Comparison$Rows <- as.factor(Comparison$Rows)
Comparison$Columns <- as.factor(Comparison$Columns)
Comparison$Approach <- factor(Comparison$Approach, levels = c("pmax", "apply.any", "apply.ifelse"))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=Comparison, aes(x=Rows, y=Duration, fill=Approach)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) +
  facet_wrap(~ Columns, strip.position = "bottom") +
  theme(strip.placement = "outside") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired") + 
  labs(title="Approach Efficiency", x="Size of Data Frame (top: Cols/ bottom: Rows)", y = "Duration µs")


Comparison$RefValue <- Comparison$Duration[rep(seq(1, 25, 3), each=3)]
Comparison$Relative <- Comparison$Duration / Comparison$RefValue

ggplot(data=Comparison, aes(x=Rows, y=Relative, fill=Approach)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) +
  facet_wrap(~ Columns, strip.position = "bottom") +
  theme(strip.placement = "outside") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired") +
  labs(title="Relative Efficiency", x="Size of Data Frame (Cols/Rows)", y = "Duration µs")
```